# Bandwith for streaming multiple channels

Tags: software-defined-radio

what is the preferred bandwith for streaming multiple channels? How does the antenna affects the frequency when your hosting in the computer?

Comment: Hi Sataniel, 1. multiple channels of what? 2. streaming – over what medium? within the context of radio, we usually talk about *transmissions*, the word *streaming* usually arises in packeted computer networks, so I'm a bit confused about what your actual medium is? 3. frequency of what? 4. "hosting in the computer": really not sure what that is, please explain!

Answer (score 1):

Great question sataniel. In essence the total bandwidth depends on the bandwidth of each channel. For example with FM radio the band is divided into 100 channels and each has 200kHz. Of course the antenna can receive them all, otherwise people would have to change out the antenna on their car for example but even if you wanted to stream 1,000 channels you can buy a special antenna that can handle them all. The real limiting factor is the transmitter/receiver, more specifically what it can do and what filtering is in place. The computer doesn't produce the frequency, only it probably produces the audio and it controls the transmitter/receiver. Another thing to keep in mind is the more channels that you stream at the same time the more the transmitting power is spread out so it will affect your range. Let me know if you have any more questions and we'll get them answered immediately :)